# Enum serialization as string without string quotes

Tags: c#, serialization, jsonconvert

I want to serialize enum as string using `JSON.NET` but I want `Enum` value to serialize without string quotes

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    enum Gender { Male, Female }

    class Test
    {
        public Gender { get; set; }
    }
```

Right now I'm getting output as `{ "Gender": "Male" }`

```
{ "Gender": Male }  //Male is without quotes
```

Comment: Why would you want this? Strings have to have quotes in JSON.

Comment: This seems like XY problem

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you assuming there's going to be a javascript variable with the same name, or...? JSON doesn't have an enum type, so you have to choose between string and number - and strings need to be quoted.

Comment: I know why you want this, because I got into a similar situation. You may want the string version of the enum to use internally. Do it like this

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourEnum).Replace("\"", "")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible because that json will be invalid. You can check how valid json looks like on https://jsonlint.com.

All JSON Convert libraries are following valid json structure, you can always write your own json converter to do that, but I wouldn't recommend that at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible (and really not recommended) because it does not respect JSON syntax.

See : [https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp][1]

In JSON, values must be one of the following data types:

a string
a number
an object (JSON object)
an array
a boolean
null